# Azerothcore Authserver and Worldserver won't start

Tags: azerothcore

I just compiled **AzerothCore** on **Wndows 10 64bit**, setup **database**, **configuration** files and **data files** (dbc, maps, vmaps, etc).
When I tried to start `authserver.exe` or `worldserver.exe` they just closed suddenly without any error or any log file created.

Comment: glad that you solved already, **ANOTHER TIP**: open `worldserver.exe` and `authserver.exe` from the terminal (e.g. git bash, cmd, etc..) so you will see the errors there

Comment: thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

#### Fixed:

Do NOT just rename the .dist configuration files!
Copy/paste .dist authserver and worldserver configuration files then rename them and leave .dist configuration files untouched.

#### **What was my issue?**

I renamed authserver.conf.dist and worldserver.conf.dist to no .dist extension which caused the issue.

#### **How to avoid this issue?**

Do **NOT** just rename the **.dist** configuration files!
Copy/paste **.dist** authserver and worldserver configuration files then rename them and leave **.dist** configuration files untouched.